# android get data from two cursors in one sorted by date list

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to display phone numbers from call history and inbox message in one `listView` sorted by date. I am using two cursors; one retrieves calls, and second retrieves incoming messages. Two of them sorted by date. But first I populate contacts and then messages. 
How can I populate this list with contacts and messages sorted by date?

Here my code:

```
    public static List<Call> getCallHistory() {
    boolean filter = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("filter", 0) == 1;
    String[] strFields = { CallLog.Calls._ID, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.DATE,
            CallLog.Calls.DURATION };
    String strOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    final Cursor cursorCall = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, strFields, null, null, strOrder);

    List<Call> callList = new ArrayList<Call>();

    while (cursorCall.moveToNext()) {
        Call call = new Call();
        call.setNumber(cursorCall.getString(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)));
        if (cursorCall.getInt(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)) == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE) {
            call.setOut(true);
        } else {
            call.setOut(false);
        }

        call.setName(cursorCall.getString(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)));
        call.setTime(cursorCall.getLong(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
        call.setDuration(cursorCall.getLong(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));

        if (filter && cursorCall.getString(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)) != null) {
            continue;
        }
        callList.add(call);
    }
    cursorCall.close();
    return getMessageHistory(callList);
    // return callList;
}

public static List<Call> getMessageHistory(List<Call> callList) {
    String[] projection = { "address", "date", "body" };
    String sortOrder = "date DESC";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, sortOrder);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        Call call = new Call();
        call.setNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
        call.setTime(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
        call.setBody(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")));
        call.setSms(true);

        callList.add(call);
    }
    return callList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Android [MergeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html), it is created just for that purpose.

In your case something like

```
Cursor cursorCall = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, strFields, null, null, strOrder);
Cursor cursorInbox = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, sortOrder);
Cursor merged = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] { cursorCall, cursorInbox });
```

If the columns not matching up causes problems, you can use [CursorWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html) to align them.

Comment: Can you provide an example of using mergeCursor?

Comment: I updated my answer, but the mergecursor is pretty straightforward and I dont have your complete code in order to build out the entire solution

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't help me. I handle it using Comparator jave class wich sort list byt date. If someone need the solution I can write it below.

Comment: OK, just so you know, it sounds like you are building up 2 lists in memory, combining them, and then sorting them in memory. That's fine for small datasets but if the user has a huge number of calls and messages you are going to run into memory problems.

Comment: Yes I combining two lists in one, and then I am soring only one list